# How to assign event.Target.Name & Values in JS file when the event is taking place from Lightning Radio button in HTML?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html

I am writing a code in JS to receive name and value attributes from Lightning-Input Radio button where event will take place on selection. But in JS file, its giving me an error while assigning the event values to const variables. Please help.

**HTML CODE**

`<lightning-input name={item.id} type="radio" value="a" label={item.options.a} onchange={changeHandler}></lightning-input>`

**JS CODE**

```
    changeHandler(event)
    {   
         const {name, value} = event.target;

         const name = event.target.name;
         const value1 = event.target.value;

         console.log('name', event.target.name);
         console.log('value', event.target.value);
        
    }
```

**ERROR LINES**
Note: Just added both ways of assigning values for clarification.

```
         const {name, value} = event.target;

         const name = event.target.name;
         const value1 = event.target.value;
```

**ERROR Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is not an error, but a warning. You've declared variables (name, value) but never use them in your `changeHandler()` function.

The second issue should be obvious. In your destructuring, you've already created a `name` variable. You can't re-use that variable name in `const name = event.target.name;`

The destructuring (i.e. `const {name, value} = event.target;`) means that you shouldn't need to declare any more variables (or use event.target again).

You should only need the following in your handler function's body

```
{
    const {name, value} = event.target;
    console.log('name', name);
    console.log('value', value);        
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Derek, I removed additional declaration and keeping this and still getting the same error -
  const {name, value} = event.target;

In short somehow this line is not working -  const {name, value} = event.target;

Comment: In the Console Log, I am actually getting the right values for name and value attributes

Comment: Sorry about that. I think it worked I got the issue. In the Console Log, I should not be using - event.target.name or value anymore as I am using const {name, value} = event.target. Great help. Thanks Derek.